# Change material preview default render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, eevee-render-engine

How can I change the default material render for example to cycles?
I understand that the standard render for materials is Eevee?

Comment: How do you mean by “material render?” Do you mean the file render engine, or do you mean the material preview viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't completely understand your question but by what I understood you want to change the render engine to be set to cycles by default if so here's how to do it

1. Open Blender

[image]

2. Change the options you want in this case the render engine

[image]

3.Go to File>Defaults then press save startup file

[image]

4.Reopen blender and make sure it works and then enjoy!

[image]